# Plugging in monitor causes floating ground on computer enclosure resulting in shock hazard

Tags: power-supply, ground, computers

Every connected metallic part of computer cabinet was giving shock. I diagnosed and found out that on switching monitor off stops the current leak and shocks. I fail to understand the reason for it since changing cables didn't worked. This may be a noob question but I am afraid this may damage my connected peripherals and graphic card.
Everything is connected to UPS and plugging monitor on other sockets also didn't worked.

Sorry for my naivness, any quick fixes for the time being? Quickly checked the earthing of building, its faulty so it may take some time to get the whole thing fixed, also power supplier tells they provide earthing from their side also. Tried connecting a short wire from cabinet to floor, didn't worked.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly your computer cabinet is not earthed and it probably should be. Secondly your monitor's in-built switch mode power supply probably has conducted-emission-reduction noise capacitors from both it's AC line inputs to its earth wire (which may not be connected to earth either) but it may be connected to other "chassis" parts of the monitor which will also connect to other metal parts (on your PC) via the VGA lead.

This probably means that if your normal supply voltage is (say) 220VAC, due to the capacitors mentioned above, your unearthed metal cabinet may be being raised to about 110VAC due to the capacitors acting as a potential divider across live and neutral.

Comment: Removing VGA lead did not helped only when the power of monitor is switched off, the cabinet doesn't give shock. Yes its 220VAC

Comment: @flanker the basic problem is that I don't think your monitor power lead is receiving a correct earth. If you have an ac voltmenter you can possibly confirm this by measuring the "shock" voltage. If it is 110Vac (or roundabout) then it is a bad earth somewhere.

Comment: Based on the OPs symptoms I would assume the computer equipment is all plugged into a power strip which has earth connections, but that the earth from the power system is not properly connected to actual earth.